# Recursive search of all viable paths in graph by edge length

Tags: c++, path, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have school assigment to create a program which gets a graph and finds out mininal spanning tree with condition that path between two points (which are preselected on run start) will be shortest by **NUMBER OF EDGES** between them.

The task itself is OK but where I struggle is optimization. When I find my path between A and B (preselected points) I try to recursively find all other possible options by DFS and then do MSTs and choose the smallest. Since the path must be of lowest number of edges and I found one of those paths by first BFS I know that I can cut of my DFS search after X recursions where X is number of edges between A in B found in the BFS. It works very fast in certain types of graphs (where number of edges is to 3 times number of vertexes) but when edges are for example 10 times bigger it just runs without stopping.

I asked my friend for a hint and he said me he uses BFS for recursively finding the other paths, and he is okay, but what is the performance difference? DFS will try first to run down and stops when reach the certain point or wastes hops avaiable, BFS goes wide first and then ends all paths at the same depth step but still I do same ammount of hopping right?

What am I missing here? Or did I understand him wrong? Thanks for any ideas.

*EDIT: I tried to check which edges I already visited in the particular DFS run to avoid going opposite direction, back to the point where i was and so on but it only generated delay on certain group of graphs while not helping noticably with others.*

*EDIT2: swapped edge and vertex quantity (cant be more vertexes than edges)*

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: Sorry, I cant do that (we are not allowed to put it anywhere online and also if I did and by chance someone copied it to their task, I would risk expulsion). Is there some further explanation I can do? I am still working on it, and I realise why the solution is ineffective but I cannot understand why BFS should be any different.

Comment: Is the graph connected?  And can you assume there is a path from A to B?

Comment: Yes and yes (since I find the path by first doing one BFS).

Comment: Well you cannot avoid doing BFS for shortest path (although you can optimize it by returning as soon as you know a branch is bad).  Once you've found the shortest path, you can run Prim's.  I'm not sure why you want to do DFS?  edit: it may be possible to combine the steps.  not 100% sure.  but perhaps the order of evaluating your queue could effectively do prims edit2: pretty sure it's not possible to combine steps if MST if based on weights and path is based on edge count

Comment: Ignore my previous comment.  I think it's possible to do BFS and at the same time calculate MST.  Start from A.  Use a priority Q by lowest weight first.  Add every edge to your MST that wouldn't cause a cycle. Every time you find a new path to B check if it's better and if it would cause a cycle.  If so, remove the worst edge connected to B and use your new one.  I do not have a proof that this is correct, but it seems to mix Prims and Dijkstra

Comment: What I am trying to understand is why BFS should be asymptotically faster than DFS? DFS looked to me more natural for this task, thats just reason, why i picked it (all was in 4 lines of code recursion). I combined BFS/DFS approach to make flags for possible candidates in speed of O(Edges) and then use DFS to combine. Almost all passed now (mb if I iterate on that I would be able to make pass all of them) while I managed to maintain most of the speed for the cases I was way faster then reference. When I am done I can post logical steps but I still dont see why BFS > DFS, I just dont see it.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash to your second comment (not sure if I get you correctly) I dont think that it covers all scenarios. Image the whole path from A to B in MST is longer by number of edges than the shortest possible which might weight more. I am looking for shortest path by number of edges between those two points.

Comment: Both algorithms find all paths.  But you can return early if you're on a path longer than one you already found.  So the better algorithm will find the shortest path first.  DFS will run down a path right away.  It might get lucky, but probably it'll find several paths before getting to the best one.  BFS will probably find the shortest path first.  It might be helpful to do an example on paper.  BTW DFS tends to be good if you want to know if a path exists/to find any old path.

Comment: In response to your response... that's why you may have to remove edges from your MST.  If you find a shorter (by number of edges) path from A to B, then you need to undo some work

Comment: Hm, I tried to do it on the paper too, but still, I know the path will be X long (I already run BFS once). In BFS I go to all adjacent then to all adjacent of adjacent and so on for X hops then write down all complete paths. In DFS I do the hops first then cut it when too long and get back. Either way I think I will do the same ammount of work. It seems same to me. :D

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash True but then I would face similar problem with (in my opinion) less intuitive approach. Still thank you for the idea. :)

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash After more digging now it seems it might be problem somewhere else. The recursive path finding now runs really fast, but Jarnik's (Prim's) algorithm seems to be the bottleneck. I will maybe need to use Kruskal. Anyway when solved I will look through it and try to summarize it into some answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**So I finished my assigment and when looking for other paths/all paths between two points A/B, DFS and BFS gets the same result as far as I found out.**

The key for me was right optimization of solution. My final solution combines going wide with going deep and works like this (maybe it can be done faster but I doubt it):

1. We know the length (in number of edges) between points A/B (we
       ran BFS once to find out path).
2. We run something like BFS from
       end point B and in every vertex we make mark how much hops we did
       from the end and call this again on all outgoing edges (we stop when
       hops == lengthOfPath(A,B)).
3. Then we do DFS from source point A
       and combine all vertexes which hold proper hop value into the path
       by recursion.

In other words we mark all point by their reachability from B and then from A we go over those accessible (with set value other than default and with proper value of hops from A) and combine all possible paths together.

*There are our paths. (I left this vague intentionally because task is still active). If anyone would need better explanation in future, post comment and I will elaborate. If someone finds better solution, post it as your answer and if right I will tick it as right answer.*